# Open terminal after running shell script

Tags: linux, bash, console

I have a shell script for my LXDE desktop, which runs `rdiff-backup`. What I would like is for this to open up a terminal with the output.

Coming from Windows, this would automatically be done. (example, run batch file with `xcopy` for backup). How can I do this on Linux?

Comment: The only stupid question is the one not asked ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xterm has the `-e` flag, which can run a script/command.  Other terms should have similar.

```
xterm [other_flags] -e path_to_your_script &
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a launcher for the shell script that runs it in a terminal.